# change dropdown menu text alignment materialize 1.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize, text-alignment

I'm using materialize 1.0.0
I want to change dropdown menu text alignment to right ... but jquery options won't work
even CSS doesn't respond (text-align:right !important;)
right class or right-align

I decided to change all J codes

HELP...

Comment: Check the alignment options in the docs here: https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: thanks but I already read instructions

Comment: please add your code in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in *materialize.css* file for the classes which you need to customize. In this case, `.dropdown-content li` class needs to be edited.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a class='dropdown-trigger btn btn-large' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">
            <i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">
            <i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-content li {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
});
```

**Right Aligned text in Dropdown**

[image: Dropdown - Right Alignment]

Comment: thanks .. I already found it <3 the thing is am trying so much codes and I forgot about CSS thing haha... but you have my respects

Comment: Alright, no problem, if the answer is same then you can accept it so that it'll not be included in unanswered quetions.